Why does an email NOT get delivered to a shared mail box and distribution list, but does to a single user?
We have an issue with (not)receiving email from one particular external sender that we can't figure out. An email gets sent from this sender to three types of emails. A single user email, a shared mail box and a distribution group email. The email arrives in the individuals inbox, but doesn't get delivered to the shared mail box or the distribution list email addresses. We checked quarantine(MS Defender), and rejected email list however even though it gets delivered to the single user, there are no quarantine/rejection notifications for the ones that didn't arrive into the shared/DL addresses?
Could anybody have any ideas of what we would check in order to get them delivered. Is it a Defender rule that stops the mail BEFORE quarantine? Is it a SPF/DKIM/DMARC issue - if so, why would it get delivered to single user and not shared/DL? Or is it a O365 issue with the Shared/DL not having licenses? or of course, another issue.
Thanks all for your thoughts. I'm not technical so any answers I will pass on to our IT company to look into (They're also in the dark as to why they're not getting delivered).

How did you confirm that the sender did in fact send the email to all three recipient email addresses?

Hi @joeqwerty, I talked to their I.T. guys who sent screenshots of the emails confirmed sent from their system. I also should add, we changed from MS Defender to another product, which I believe is when the issue started. Then we rolled back to Defender due to various issues. So as we're the ones that changed - im assuming the issue is on our end.

Are all recipients in the same domain? Are MX records correct?
For DLs to be able to accept external emails, you need to allow unauthenticated senders to send to them, but since this worked before the change you mentioned to Joe, this is probably involving the 3rd party filtering product change.
